# Which ngx-skeleton-loader version is suitable for Angular 12?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12, skeleton-ui, skeleton

I encountered an error while trying to install the latest version of ngx-skeleton-loader on Angular 12.Which ngx-skeleton-loader version is suitable for Angular 12 ?

"I want to implement ngx-skeleton-loader in my Angular 12 project."

Comment: You can check their [changelog](https://github.com/willmendesneto/ngx-skeleton-loader/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md). It seems like version 4.0.0 could be a good fit for you.